# Clarification question on applying divergence theorem to $\nabla \cdot (u \nabla u)$ on a compact manifold without boundary

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, divergence-theorem

I'm following the solutions given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895595/kernel-of-the-laplacian-on-a-compact-manifold) post.

Basically, they are trying to prove that the kernel of the Laplace operator on a compact manifold without boundary is just made up of constant functions.

In the second answer (the one by Robert Lewis), he integrates $\nabla \cdot (u \nabla u) = \langle\nabla u, \nabla u\rangle + u \nabla ^2 u$ over the manifold and applies the divergence theorem to the left hand side to get

$\int _M \langle\nabla u, \nabla u\rangle dV = -\int_M u \nabla ^2 u \mbox{ dV}$.

When I tried applying the divergence theorem I got

$\int _{\partial D} \vec{n} \cdot u \nabla u  \mbox{ dS} = \int _M \langle\nabla u, \nabla u\rangle dV + \int_M u \nabla ^2 u \mbox{ dV}$.

I know that I need $\int _{\partial D} \vec{n} \cdot u \nabla u  \mbox{ dS} =0$ but I'm unsure of how to reason this given that there is no boundary.This is probably a silly question, but can someone please explain this point further? The rest of the solution from the post I'm referencing absolutely made sense. This is just where I was stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Use `\langle,\rangle` for the angled braces

Comment: If there is no boundary, you integrate over an empty set.

Comment: @stange Okay so I was wondering that. So since we're integrating over a set of 0 measure, the result is 0, correct?

Comment: @FShrike thanks! Noted

Comment: @k12345 Exactly.

Comment: @stange thank you!